# Adobe Analytics API - Real Time Classification

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I need to get from Omniture real time API a classify eVar, exclude some value, and then breackdown its with sitesection.

I try with this query:

```
{
    "reportDescription": {
        "source": "realtime",
        "reportSuiteID": "**RSID**", //MY REPORT SUITE
        "metrics": [{
            "id": "instances"
        }],
        "elements": [{
            "id": "evar", //MY EVAR
            "top": 100,
            "classification": "Real Time", //CLASSIFICATION NAME
            "search": {
                "type": "NOT",
                "keywords": ["somevalue"] //THE VALUE TO EXCLUDE
            }
        },{
            "id" : "sitesection",
            "top" : 1
        }],
        "dateGranularity": "minute:1",
        "dateFrom": "-1 minute"
    }
}
```

But in the JSON response I see "somevalue" how if it not excluded.
The strange thing is that if I remove the "breakdown" (with sitesection) the classification filter seems to works fine.

I can't use classification filter if a breackdown is used in real time report? I can't find any documentation about that.

---

An other thing is that if I request a report with the classification, without any search, I receve the response but there is a lot of "::Unspecified::". The problem is that the "::Unspecified::" seems to be the last datas that Omniture receves form my webpages. I think this means that classifications are not in real time, also if you can to use it in real time report.

Comment: evars can't be used for real-time reports so you shouldn't be able to pull data for this at all. You should be getting an invalid report response from that.  Please show the elements/metrics you are actually trying to pull.

Comment: @CrayonViolent I try to pull custom evar93, and You can't set up a evar in real time report if you use the Omniture console. If you do this via API you can set up evars instead props, take a look: https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/documentation/analytics-reporting-1-4/real-time

However i already set up an evar and I already have the response, my problerm is only with Classification.