# Large extraction with Adobe analytics API V2.0

Tags: python, api, adobe-analytics

My problem is: I want to perform large queries using the API 2.0 with a python function that extracts data from one dimension (Posts) (about 60.000 lines or more) and then break it down by another dimension (Tags) querying each of the lines of the first dimension (Posts).

Why is this happening: I'm using the Adobe Analytics API 2.0 to perform some extractions including one particular that is quite "large" for the API. Right now I've got a dimension (dim1) of Posts that I need to breakdown by the dimension Tags (dim2). I'm facing here two problems, the first one is that the Dimension Posts(dim1) has over 60.000 rows for each day. So I need to query each of these 60.000 rows with each identifier (item_id) and perform another query.

What I saw reading carefully the documentation is that the maximum of lines in each query is 50.000 rows for the version [1.4](https://www.datanalyst.info/python/adobe-api/adobe-analytics-api-retrievereport/)  and the [2.0](https://adobeexchangeec.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035110451-Adobe-Analytics-Pulling-Large-Data-Sets#:%7E:text=First%2C%20the%20reports%20are%20paginated,is%20120%20requests%20per%20minute.)

Is there any chance to extend the number of rows to perform these large queries? Can I skip somehow the 50.000 rows limit?

In the other hand I saw that these kind of breakdown queries are quite slow in the version 2.0 of the API that I'm working with, so in some cases it takes about two hours just to collect 1.000 sub queries? dimension rows. Anyone can tell me if the version 1.4 has better performance in these kind of queries? Is the version 1.4 of the API faster in this kind of operations?

I'm a little afraid that Adobe is going to cut the service for the 1.4 API this year in April, I found only this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53553711/adobe-analytics-api) but not sure about it?

I'm checking regularly the [git](https://github.com/pitchmuc/adobe_analytics_api_2.0/blob/master/aanalytics2/aanalytics2.py) source of the project but for the moment I haven't seen a solution here.

```
    pageResults = agsIns.getReport(myJsonF, 70000, 70000, item_id=True);
dataR=pageResults['data'];#only returns 50.000 registers, no matter what I do with the limit parameter
```

**UPDATE**: I've tried to visualize the information using the settings.page parameter as written in the solution bellow but haven't any luck with it. Somebody knows an example with this parameter in order to test it.

```
pageResults = agsIns.getReport(myJsonF, 70000, 70000, item_id=True);
```

Then I've altered my json file to print next pages by updating after each query every page using the "settings.page"=0,1,2,3.... in the JSON as bellow but it didn't work.

```
"dimension": "variables/evar23",
"settings": {
    "countRepeatInstances": true,
    "limit": 50,
    "page": 0,
    "nonesBehavior": "return-nones"
}
```

I change the parameter "page" with the values 1, 2, 3... but I always get the same resultset, What am I doing wrong? (I put an example about how I change the page number, I know that it is doing it well in the variable because I see it in the debugging console)

```
 json_obj['settings']['page'] = 3;
```

(Thank you Crayon Violent, I corrected the mistake, I posted quickly and didn't realized the error on the dimension)

I've checked some links but none of them answer this question:

[Fetch Data using adobe-analytics-api-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63259686/fetch-data-using-adobe-analytics-api-2-0)

[Connect Adobe Analytics to MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55712781/connect-adobe-analytics-to-mysql)

[Adobe Analytics API JSON query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667623/adobe-analytics-api-json-query)

[Adobe Analytics API - Real Time Classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826140/adobe-analytics-api-real-time-classification)

Comment: Well I know limit+page works because I have done it myself. You can also test it out for yourself with Swagger UI here https://adobedocs.github.io/analytics-2.0-apis/  . Sounds like you have other issues with your payload or script in general. Well for example IDK if you have typo just here or in your script too but I think "variables/datarange" is a typo and should be "variables/daterange". Or maybe your loop isn't actually looping or your variable you use for page parameter isn't really incrementing in your loop, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. I haven't done any formal benchmarking but my own anecdotal evidence from experience working with both, I personally don't think the 1.4 endpoint is any faster or slower than the 2.0 endpoint. AFAIK on the backend it ultimately makes the same db queries etc. only real change is the syntax. But unless Adobe wants to chime in here, I don't think it's going to get better than anecdotal.
2. Even if 1.4 were faster, I'd still recommend using 2.0. Adobe  hasn't yet given any official end of life announcement for 1.4, but 1.3 just expired so I figure probably sooner rather than later 1.4 is up next. My guess is probably the only reason it hasn't already been marked is because there are still some things in 1.4 you can't do in 2.0, because reasons. But this is all speculation on my end. Nothing solid other than the general principle that things deprecate and end of life over time, so unless you have some really compelling reason not to use the latest (e.g. what you need to do is not available in 2.0), seems to me best practice is to work with the latest version.
3. Yes, the API will only return up to 50k rows *at a time* with `top` (1.4) or `settings.limit` (2.0). But you can use that along with [`reportDescription.startWith` (1.4)](https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-1.4-apis/blob/master/docs/reporting-api/data_types/r_reportDescriptionElement.md) or [`settings.page` (2.0)](https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-2.0-apis/blob/master/reporting-guide.md#paginating-reports) to get the next set of results. Similar in concept to pagination.